# creating new variable in a dataframe

Tags: r

I have a dataframe df that contains a factor in column A (e.g. companies | persons).
I have data in column B and C. Now I want to create a new variable/column that uses data from B if it is a company and uses data from C it is a private person.

df$D <- (when (A == company) then B else when (B == person) then C

Thank you for all responses.

Comment: `df$D <- ifelse(df$A == 'company', df$B, df$C)`

Comment: Very good. Thanky you! What would I need to do if A was not binary but included just different names (Alice, Bob, Charles, ...)?

Comment: Look at `case_when` from the `dplyr` package, which is like the non-binary version of `ifelse`

Answer (score 1):

Sample code:

`ifelse` example as suggested by `@Allan Cameron`

```
df$d <- ifelse(df$a == "company", df$b, df$c)

  df

         a  b  c  d
1  company  1 10  1
2  company  2 20  2
3  company  3 30  3
4  company  4 40  4
5  company  5 50  5
6  company  6 60  6
7  persons  7 70 70
8  persons  8 80 80
9  persons  9 10 10
10 persons 10 10 10
11 persons 11 10 10
```

`case_when` example from `dplyr()`

```
df %>% 
   mutate(e = case_when (b <=6 & c>=10 ~ "company", d > 6 ~ "persons", b==9 & c==10 & d==10~"NA"))

df

         a  b  c  d       e
1  company  1 10  1 company
2  company  2 20  2 company
3  company  3 30  3 company
4  company  4 40  4 company
5  company  5 50  5 company
6  company  6 60  6 company
7  persons  7 70 70 persons
8  persons  8 80 80 persons
9  persons  9 10 10      NA
10 persons 10 10 10 company
11 persons 11 10 10 company
```

Sample data:

```
a<-c("company","company","company","company","company","company","persons","persons","persons","persons","persons")
b<-c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11)
c<-c(10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,10,10,10)


df<-cbind(a,b,c)
df<-data.frame(df)

df$a<-factor(df$a, levels=c("company","persons"))
```